# Late 2015 iMac (purchased early 2017) running very slow

Tags: macos, imac, memory

My iMac has been running very slow since purchase. I've done all the tests and checks I can think of, below is a copy of the EtreCheck report that was done today. Reviewing it, other than not enough RAM (which is not fixable) I'm not sure what else to do.

---

```
EtreCheck version: 3.3.3 (397)
Report generated 2017-06-02 15:29:35
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 9:27
Performance: Below Average

Click the [Lookup] links for more information from Apple Support Communities.
Click the [Details] links for more information about that line.

Problem: Beachballing
Description:
^

Hardware Information: ⓘ
    iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2015) 
    [Technical Specifications] - [User Guide] - [Warranty & Service]
    iMac - model: iMac16,2
    1 2.8 GHz Intel Core i5 (i5-5575R) CPU: 4-core
    8 GB RAM Not upgradeable
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            4 GB DDR3 1867 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM0
            4 GB DDR3 1867 MHz ok
    Bluetooth: Good - Handoff/Airdrop2 supported
    Wireless: Unknown
Video Information: ⓘ
    Intel Iris Pro Graphics 6200 - VRAM: 1536 MB
        DA220HQL 1920 x 1080 @ 60 Hz
        iMac 1920 x 1080

System Software: ⓘ
    macOS Sierra  10.12.5 (16F73) - Time since boot: about 5 hours

Disk Information: ⓘ
    APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662 disk0 : (1 TB) (Rotational)
    [Show SMART report]
        EFI (disk0s1 - MS-DOS FAT32) <not mounted> : 210 MB 
        Recovery HD (disk0s3 - Journaled HFS+) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 650 MB 
        Macintosh HD (disk1 - Journaled HFS+) /  [Startup]: 998.98 GB (888.59 GB free)
            Core Storage: disk0s2 999.35 GB Online

USB Information: ⓘ
     USB30Bus 
        Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 
        Apple Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) 

Thunderbolt Information: ⓘ
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Configuration files: ⓘ
    /etc/hosts - Count: 6

Gatekeeper: ⓘ
    Mac App Store and identified developers

Kernel Extensions: ⓘ
        /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox
    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (5.1.18) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (5.1.18) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (5.1.18) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (5.1.18) [Lookup]

System Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    6 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    178 Apple tasks
    [running]    79 Apple tasks
    [killed]    19 Apple tasks
    19 processes killed due to insufficient RAM

System Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    41 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    175 Apple tasks
    [running]    90 Apple tasks
    [killed]    11 Apple tasks
    11 processes killed due to insufficient RAM

Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist (? 3dab720a be93c7fb - installed 2017-03-03) [Lookup]

Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [loaded]    com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2017-01-12) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2017-01-12) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.daemon.plist (Google, Inc. - installed 2017-04-17) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2016-04-11) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist (Shell Script e3fefdd2 - installed 2017-03-03) [Lookup]
    [not loaded]    org.virtualbox.startup.plist (Shell Script 700b9385 - installed 2017-04-19) [Lookup]

User Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [running]    com.spotify.webhelper.plist (Spotify - installed 2017-05-30) [Lookup]
    [not loaded]    org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist (Oracle America, Inc. - installed 2017-04-19) [Lookup]

Internet Plug-ins: ⓘ
    AdobePDFViewerNPAPI: 17.009.20044 (installed 2017-04-13) [Lookup]
    AdobePDFViewer: 17.009.20044 (installed 2017-04-13) [Lookup]
    QuickTime Plugin: 7.7.3 (installed 2017-05-30)
    JavaAppletPlugin: Java 8 Update 121 build 13 (installed 2017-03-03) Check version
    AdobeAAMDetect: 3.0.0.0 (installed 2017-03-14) [Lookup]

3rd Party Preference Panes: ⓘ
    Java (installed 2016-12-12) [Lookup]

Time Machine: ⓘ
    Time Machine not configured!

Top Processes by CPU: ⓘ
         4%     WindowServer -daemon
         3%     ps -raxcww -o %mem, [and 3 more arguments]
         3%     kernel_task
         2%     ps -raxcww -o %mem, [and 3 more arguments]
         2%     mds

Top Processes by Memory: ⓘ
    817 MB      kernel_task
    532 MB      VBoxHeadless --comment default --startvm [and 3 more arguments]
    200 MB      Google Chrome -psn_0_61455
    197 MB      Code Helper --type=renderer --js-flags=--nolazy [and 15 more arguments]
    192 MB      Google Chrome Helper --type=renderer [and 15 more arguments]

Top Processes by Network Use: ⓘ
    Input       Output      Process name
    4 MB        299 KB      mDNSResponder
    917 KB      252 KB      VBoxHeadless --comment default --startvm [and 3 more arguments]
    1 MB        1 KB        netbiosd
    19 KB       34 KB       apsd
    5 KB        21 KB       assistantd

Top Processes by Energy Use: ⓘ
     13.34  VBoxHeadless --comment default --startvm [and 3 more arguments]
     10.78  Google Chrome Helper --type=renderer [and 15 more arguments]
      8.20  Google Chrome -psn_0_61455
      6.44  WindowServer -daemon

Virtual Memory Information: ⓘ
    1.66 GB     Available RAM
    52 MB       Free RAM
    6.34 GB     Used RAM
    1.61 GB     Cached files
    84 MB       Swap Used

Diagnostics Information: ⓘ
    2017-06-02 09:58:19    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Installer Progress_2017-06-02-095819_[redacted].crash
        com.apple.Installer-Progress - /System/Library/CoreServices/Installer Progress.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer Progress
        Application Specific Information:
        Assertion failed: (gfx_plugin_data.service[i] == gfx_plugin_data.service[i - 1]), function validate_plugin_data, file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenGL/OpenGL-14.0.16/GFXShared/gfx_plugin.c, line 1493.
    2017-06-01 15:20:56    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/GitHub Desktop_2017-06-01-152056_[redacted].crash
        /Applications/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub Desktop
        Application Specific Information:
        Performing @selector(_close:) from sender _NSThemeCloseWidget 0x608000195470
```

Comment: What do you mean "not enough RAM?" What does activity monitor report when everything is slow?

Comment: @Allan is right, you should be checking Activity Monitor. Basically, not having *enough RAM* depends on what you're using your iMac for (8GB is enough for many users, but won't be if you're performing heavy tasks). So, on that note, could you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/285654/edit) your question to list *al the tests and checks* you've already done and a description or screenshot of your Activity Monitor report (taken when the iMac is running slowly).

Comment: Thanks to @Monomeeth for cleaning up the post.  After scanning through I see two major issues:  1)  you are out of memory so your Mac is going to swap space and 2)you have a 5400RPM spinning drive.  This means that being out of memory, your Mac is forced to go to the absolutely slowest spinning HDD out there for virtual memory.  You will see an immediate bump in speed if you upgrade to an SSD, but only by a marginal amount.   For all intents and purposes, you have outstripped the capacity of your iMac - look at getting something with more horsepower.